# Facebook won't publish scores if it comes from a mobile device?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, mobile, unity-game-engine, prime31

I have been working with the Prime31 Social Media plugin to post a user's score from a Unity game that has been built for ios and android. After a long discussion with someone on the support forums for Prime31 it ended with he thinks that Facebook won't publish open graph stories when a user updates the score if the app is on a mobile device, that that is a feature reserved for native Facebook apps.

This makes little sense to me as I'm sure i've seen open graph score updates from games like Candy Crush and I believe the plugin makes the same call to update the score as you would if you were using PHP in a native Facebook app.

Currently I can post the user's score and find their score using the Open Graph Explorer, it is being updated on Facebook, however it has never been published anywhere. I have tried to make it a high score and even had another account that was my friend pass my score in the game. It never published the score for either user.

I know there are a few questions on Stack that are the same, but I have checked for every solution that was proposed in each question with no result.

**Here is what I already know:**

- When I look up the scores for my account in the open graph explorer,
  the score is there, so it makes it to facebook and is saved as my
  score for the app, but it is never posted to my news feed or activity
  stream.
- I know that facebook won't post the story unless it is a high score
  or a score that has been passed by a friend. The scores I am posting 
  increment, they have always been higher than the previous and it has 
  never been published.
- I do have the publish_actions permission authorized
- I have the 'web' selected in the app settings and it is categorized
  as a Game.
- I have been able to post to my wall before so I know the code to
  login and authenticate works, I also know because the score it being 
  set in the facebook api, as mentioned above.

The link to the prime 31 support forum [here](http://prime31.com/support/3904/post-score-boolean-returned-what-does-it-signify)